# Executing JavaScript function on a linked page

Tags: javascript, html

Can I link to a page on my website using an Href and executing a function when loaded. I don't want the function to load automatically (and that is easy to do anyway) because there is multiple ways to enter the page.

```
<div onclick="location.href='index.html'; hideshow(blog-post-grundig)">
```

The above link takes you to the page and I would like the function to execute on that page when that page is loaded, see function below:

```
function hideshow(btn) {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="blog-post"]');
    a.forEach(a => {
      if (a.id == btn) a.style.display = "block";
      if (a.id != btn) a.style.display = "none";
    })
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Can I link to a page on my website using an Href and executing a function when loaded.` ... No you can't. The page to be loaded has to run its own scripts.

Comment: You could send a "get" var that where your other page detects it and handles the logic you want accordingly on the other page.

Comment: You can pass a parameter in the query string, and read it on the other page in order to determine what to do

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that - JS executes on the current page only.

You should use an anchor for this:

```
<a href="index.html#blog-post-grundig">
```

Then on *index.html*, check the `location.hash` on load and do automatically execute the function if a blog post is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query string to the href and that will be the Id for the function

Example

```js
// this object will containe all functions that you will be executing.
var functions = { hideshow:function(btn) {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="blog-post"]');
    a.forEach(a => {
      if (a.id == btn) a.style.display = "block";
      if (a.id != btn) a.style.display = "none";
    })
  } 
  }


// now when the page load 
function load(){
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const f = urlParams.get('f'); // which will be extracted from index.html?f=hideshow And that will be 'hideshow'

functions[f]("somthing")
}

load();
```

```html
<div onclick="index.html?f=hideshow">
```